# show a function not integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I show the function

$f(x,y)=1/(1+x^2+y^2+x^2\times y^2)$ not integrable on $\mathbb R^2$?

is it to do with Lebesgue theory?
so I need to show that f is everywhere continuous on $\mathbb R^2$?
but how can I show the set of points in $\mathbb R^2$ where $f$ is discontinuous has the Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: yes...I mean ℝ^2

Comment: @Cindy Looks like you should learn [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Cindy, I don't understand. Your integral *does* exist and has the value $\pi^2$. This is essentially because $\frac{1}{1 + x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2} = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$, so the iterated integral will be $(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx)^2$.